# Remove Period (.) from Dataframe Column Names

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

So I've gone through all the examples on here of replacing special characters from column names, but I can't seem to get it to work for periods.

What I've tried:

```
# works to remove spaces
df.select([F.col(c).alias(c.replace(' ', '_')) for c in df.columns])

# doesn't work to remove periods
df.select([F.col(c).alias(c.replace('.', '')) for c in df.columns])

# removes special characters except periods 
df.select([F.col(col).alias(re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z$]+","",col)) for col in df.columns])
```

I know how to change the name of a column by referencing that specific column, but this needs to change names of columns for any dataframe with columns with special characters

Specifically here is the column name that is giving me trouble: "Src. of Business Contact Full Name"

Comment: is it a reg expr so period needs to be escaped with a \ ?

Comment: please explain a little more

Comment: no luck with that

Comment: r u getting an `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException` error?

Comment: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Src. of Business Contact Full Name`' given input columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` is a deprecated method.  Why not make as simple as below?

```
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(["a biz"], columns=["Src.$ of-Business Contact` Full Name"])
df.columns = [re.sub("[ ,-]", "_", re.sub("[\.,`,\$]", "", c)) for c in df.columns]
df
```

**output**

```
    Src_of_Business_Contact_Full_Name
0   a biz
```

Comment: Another really good solution, however, is there a way to make it catch all special characters?

Comment: just extend the reg expr.  `df.columns = [re.sub("[ ,\$]", "_", re.sub("[.]", "", c)) for c in df.columns]` would then replace $ with underscore if desired

Comment: @PalaniThangaraj I've updated example to show how more special characters can be handled

Comment: The problem here is that this solution only works for pandas dataframes, not spark dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Try by **escaping** column names using **backquotes** **`col_name`**

.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('1','2')],['header','pla.nned'])
df.columns
#['header', 'pla.nned']

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select([F.col("`{0}`".format(c)).alias(c.replace('.', '')) for c in df.columns]).show()
#+------+-------+
#|header|planned|
#+------+-------+
#|     1|      2|
#+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about this using **`reduce`** and **`withColumnRenamed`**.

```
from functools import reduce

(reduce(lambda new_df, col: new_df.withColumnRenamed(col,col.replace('.','')),df.columns,df)).show()
```